# Getting the value of string from a jagged array when using option strict

Tags: vb.net

I've just started using option strict (based on advice from another question) and I'm stuck!

I have an array which contains more arrays. The second array contains strings. I can't work out how to get the values of the strings out of the second array.

```
dim sb as new stringbuilder
public sub foobar({{"abcd", "efg"},{"hjik", "lmnop"}}
 for each arr in master
  sb.AppendLine(arr(0))
 next
end sub
```

But I get a late binding error. I understand why I'm getting the error but how do I get around it?

Comment: that code wont compile event adding the missing `End Sub`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming master looks similar to what you're passing in to foobar, then arr(0) get's you to element 0 of the first dimension of the array, you'd need to iterate over that array if you want to append all elements from each second level array.

With Option Strict you will also need to declare the *type* of each variable, so it is going to get pretty "wordy":

```
Dim aryOfArrays()() As String = _
    New String()() {New String() {"1a", "1b"}, New String() {"2a", "2b"}}

For Each aryOfStrings As String() In aryOfArrays
    For Each strElement As String In aryOfStrings
        sb.AppendLine(strElement)
    Next
Next
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfky451c(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: *"With Option Strict you will also need to declare the type of each variable"* That's not exactly true ; it is only for "variable" at class/module scope but not for locals inside a method. And even then it also depend on `Option Explicit` and `Option Infer` values. illustration [there](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1d5Pe0)

Answer (score 0):

You should define variables in vb.net in the begging of the function.
Move the "dim str" to the beginning of function

[more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx)

Comment: Sorry I had abbreviated the code thinking it would be simpler. I'm not defining a variable, I'm writing the content of arr(0) to a stringbuilder. I'll edit the question